# Determinant of a Symmetric Matrix in Eigen3

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

- A program put values into a matrix to form a 3 x 3 symmetric matrix X, and then calculate determinant of X.
- The program is compiled with `g++ -Ofast`
- Will the program only use 6 floats in X for calculating the
  determinant because X is symmetric?

Program

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
template <typename T>
T symdet(T a) {
    Eigen::Matrix<T, 3, 3> X;
    X(0, 0) = a;
    X(1, 1) = 2 * a;
    X(2, 2) = 3 * a;
    X(0, 1) = X(1, 0) = 4 * a;
    X(0, 2) = X(2, 0) = 5 * a;
    X(1, 2) = X(2, 1) = 6 * a;
    return X.determinant();
}
int main() {
    srand (static_cast <unsigned> (time(0)));
    float a = static_cast<float>(rand()) / static_cast<float>(RAND_MAX);
    std::cout << symdet(a) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: test at godbolt.org shows the compiler can use registers to replace small static arrays: https://godbolt.org/g/F1grsW

Comment: If the question on using 6 floats is related to the determinant algorithm, sure it would use 6 unique numbers (even though the formula would account for all 9 numbers). If the question is on how the compiler would optimize the determinant calculations, see the above comment.

Comment: Only care about speed. less floats -> less multiplication and addition -> faster calculation.

Comment: Even if everything is on registry, for the compiler to note that x(0,1) was assigned equal to x(1,0) and therefore do a cse on that I think is extremely unlikely, even if Eugenia is a template library. If you only want to use the upper part because the matrix is symmetric, use a a library which intentionally does so (I am not familiar with Eigen). By the way, it is quite unusual in linear algebra to explicitly need the determinant. It would be interesting to know what is your use case.

Comment: @Fabio: Compiler can. See example at https://godbolt.org/g/F1grsW it has a line `tmp[4] = tmp[0] = a;`. Compiler treats `tmp[4]` and `tmp[0]` as the same thing, after converting the short static array `tmp` to registers. I'm just not sure if that is still true, after Eigen uses meta-programming to convert the matrix operations directly to simd intrinsics.

Comment: Interesting.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Probably it can because it isn't using vectorized operations anyway.
I installed a local instance of compiler explorer: https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer

C++ code:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
float symdet(float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f) {
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3> X;
    X(0, 0) = a;
    X(1, 1) =  b;
    X(2, 2) =  c;
    X(0, 1) = X(1, 0) = d;
    X(0, 2) = X(2, 0) = e;
    X(1, 2) = X(2, 1) = f;
    return X.determinant();
}
```

Assembly (g++-7 -Ofast -I):

```
symdet(float, float, float, float, float, float):
  movaps xmm6, xmm1
  mulss xmm1, xmm4
  movaps xmm7, xmm5
  mulss xmm6, xmm2
  mulss xmm7, xmm5
  mulss xmm2, xmm3
  subss xmm6, xmm7
  mulss xmm0, xmm6
  movaps xmm6, xmm4
  mulss xmm6, xmm5
  subss xmm2, xmm6
  mulss xmm2, xmm3
  mulss xmm3, xmm5
  subss xmm0, xmm2
  subss xmm3, xmm1
  mulss xmm4, xmm3
  addss xmm0, xmm4
  ret
```

The ss operations are scalar that works on just 1 float value, instead of vector operations. 
There are only 6 input values `xmm[0 - 5]`, `xmm[6, 7]` holds intermediates.